# Returning the maximum of non-null columns ​from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 4 columns, one of which is a non-null column, all others can be given a null value.
I just want a SELECT that returns results that have as many non-null columns as possible.
For example:
If I have 5 records in my Table, 1 of those records will have 3 columns with data, 2 of them will have 2 columns with data and 2 of them will have only 1 column with data. In my select, I want as a result only the first option: to bring me 3 columns with data. But it can be just 2 columns with data, it will be dynamic according to the table to be updated.

I'm using Oracle SQL.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.  What if multiple rows have the same number of non-NULL columns, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a conditional sort based on the count of non-`null` values in each row, and then a row-limiting clause (available since Oracle 12c). Assuming that the 3 nullable columns are `col1`, `col2` and `col3`, that would be:

```
select *
from mytable
order by
      case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end desc
fetch first row with ties
```

If you are running an older version of Oracle, you can get the same result with window function `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(order by
              case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
            + case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end
            + case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Can u explain more about that expression "fetch first row with ties"? What they exactly do?

Comment: This selects the first row (after the `order by` was applied). if there are ties (that is, multiple rows with the same count of non null values), they are all returned. It may bo worth mentioning that this syntax is available since Oracle 12c only.

Comment: Thanks a lot by now, but Im keeping to receive error... ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, could you help me?

Comment: @LuizGTVSilva: which version of Oraclee are you running? `select * from v$version` can tell you. Side note: you have `NOT NULL` where you should have `NULL` in the query (this does not explain why it fails, though).

Comment: I verified and I have the Oracle 11, due of this isnt working, but u helped a lot :) you saved my life

Comment: @LuizGTVSilva: ok. I updated my answer with a query for earlier versions of Oracle.